# Travis-CI builds on schedule

Tags: travis-ci

How can I set up a build schedule for Travis-CI that is not based around pushing to GitHub? I want to run Selenium tests against my production site nightly. I'm happy with a hacky solution  if official support is not present.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Travis-CI's [cron jobs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/cron-jobs/) feature was implemented in May 2016.

Answer (score 20):

I've launched a self-service app for this: https://nightli.es. Ensures the project is built at least once a day.

Answer (score 3):

I see two options which will give you full control to setup your build schedule.

- Using [Travis CI command line interface](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb) with OS task scheduler or
- You may use an external solution such as [Tron CI](http://tron-ci.herokuapp.com/) which gives you the chance to schedule as many builds you want for each project that you have on Travis CI. I've been using it for quite a time to run one of my projects twice a day and works just perfectly.

Comment: Tron CI's UI is broken. I keep getting internal server errors. (But triggering Travis builds seems to work fine.)

Comment: Tron CI: "Offline for maintenance. This app is undergoing maintenance right now. Please check back later."

Comment: As @synesso pointed out, Travis added this feature in 2016. Because of this Tron CI actually has no reason to be and it was turned off.

Comment: How can one schedule daily midnight travis build with travis command line interface? I couldn't find any option to schedule cron job build using travis cli client.